# Combining R data frame column names with levels of the column

Tags: r, vectorization

I am trying to create a function that would combine each column name with the levels (factors) of the column and return a vector with the combined names.

For a data frame
`df1 <- data.frame(v1= c('a', 'b', 'b'), v2= c('b', 'b', 'c'))`

it should return

`"v1:a" "v1:b" "v2:b" "v2:c"`

I suppose I could do this in a loop, but is there some vectorized solution available, in case the data frames are very big?

Comment: Look at `expand.grid` I suppose? It's hard to tell what your input data is like by your description.

Comment: Try `outer(names(dat), levels(dat$A), FUN= paste, sep=":")`

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions. The proposed solutions use a specific column name. What I'm after is a function that would take just the data frame as argument and return each columns name concatenated with the levels of that column. If Column named "A" would have levels "a" and "b" and column named "B" would have levels "c", "d" and "e" the vector returned from the function would have values "A:a", "A:b", "B:c", "B:d" and "B:e".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(names(df), levels(df$A), FUN= paste, sep=":") )
#[1] "A:a" "B:a" "A:b" "B:b" "A:c" "B:c"
```

#### Update

If the columns have different levels, try

```
unlist(Map(paste, colnames(df1), lapply(df1, levels), 
                          MoreArgs= list(sep=":")), use.names=FALSE)
#[1] "A:a" "A:b" "A:c" "B:c" "B:d" "B:e"
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame( A= c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'), B= c('d', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't doing the trick. This uses the levels of the column named in the function and uses that for all columns. Other columns will have different levels.

Comment: @chorin Alright, I thought your example was reflecting the actual dataset

Comment: @chorin Try `unlist(Map(paste, colnames(df1), lapply(df1, levels), MoreArgs= list(sep=":")))`

Comment: It's not working for me. 
For example the dataframe with
v1  | v2
"a" | "b"
"a" | "b"
"b" | "c"

Comment: @chorin Please update your post with a small example (just like in my post) and also the expected output based on that.  `It's not working for me`  doesn't give much info.

Comment: It's not working for me. 
For example the dataframe with
v1  | v2
"a" | "b"
"a" | "b"
"b" | "c"
outputs a vector "v1:a" "v1:b"  "v2:" when it should output "v1:a", "v1:b, "v2:b", v2:c".

Comment: @chorin As I mentioned, please update your post with a data.frame and the expected output.  Hard to read from the comments.

Comment: I understand "It's not working for me" doesn't give enough info, I was struggling to create a table of the data and run out of my 5 minutes. ;-). 
Well, markdown tables don't work, but to clarify the previous comments: I am talking about a dataframe with vectors ("a", "b", "b") and ("b", "b", "c"). The colnames would respectively be "v1" and "v2".

Comment: @chorin Is it `df1 <- data.frame(v1= c('a', 'b', 'b'), v2= c('b', 'b', 'c'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  and what is the expected output

Comment: df1 <- data.frame(v1= c('a', 'b', 'b'), v2= c('b', 'b', 'c') would be an example of the dataframe. I think strings should be factors. It should output a vector containing elements "v1:a", "v1:b, "v2:b" and "v2:c".

Comment: @chorin Based on the code in the Update, it is giving me the expected output.  So, I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, now I managed to get it working for me as well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ananda Mahto , you can use `expand.grid`along with `apply`

```
apply(expand.grid(colnames(df), levels(df$A)), 1, paste, collapse=":")

# [1]  "A:a" "B:a" "A:b" "B:b" "A:c" "B:c"
```